# SSIS vbscript for word delimits

Tags: vbscript, ssis

I researched delimit issue for a while and I pull useful codes here and there, but I can't quite put it together.
I'm trying to parse the string by word in SSIS and I NEED help on vb script component.
I need to delimit my column data to the following deliminator:
"AND","OR","****", ","
I have a table like this

ID     Description
1      apple AND orange, tangerine
2      avocado OR guacamole AND pineapple OR fruit
3      watermelon **** melon

And I want to parse the data like this

ID     Description
1      apple
1      orange
1      tangerine
2      avocado
2      guacamole
2      pineapple
2      fruit
3      watermelon
3      melon

Thank you.

Comment: You need something a lot more complicated than VBSCRIPT. You need a script component, since you need to take one row in, and produce three or more rows out.

Comment: What exactly is problem? Splitting words, writing multiple output rows for one input row, ...? Post code You already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to parte string by words is enought a combination of [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_replace.asp) a [split](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_split.asp):

(I assume that you know how to take ID)

```
split(
  replace(
   replace (
     replace( Description, "AND", ","),
     "OR", ","
   ),
   "**", ","
  ), ","
)
```

this return a array of elements as you ask for:

```
id = 2
a=my_previous_functions_combination("avocado OR guacamole AND pineapple OR fruit")
for each fruit in a
    do something with id and fruit
next
```

so far, help with vb. I don't know what you want to do in SSIS: a calculated member? a named set? Extend fact table? Read second answer part:

**Second part:**

To convert a row in multiples row you need a script. You can find a good example in [SSIS - Script Component, Split single row to multiple rows](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/sudeep/archive/2010/11/24/ssis-script-component-split-single-row-to-multiple-rows.aspx) post.

Comment: This is simple and perfect for my need. The codes that I scrapped from internet was returning a parsed string array and it was difficult to integrated into SSIS. Thank you!

Comment: @ElegantFellow, what was finally the solution? First or second part of answer?